# Image As a Button -- Changes Image When Clicked

Tags: html, button, image

I'm using a combination of html and very basic jQuery in order to make an img that functions like a button so that when the img is clicked, the src of the image (src1) changes to another src (src2, that being the image of the button having been pushed down).
I'm trying to make it so that if that same image (now src2) is clicked, then it changes back to the original src (src1).

I hope that wasn't a headache to understand, and I can clarify if needed.

Here's what I have for code:

```
<!--Html-->
<body>
<img id="pixelbutton" src="images/pixelbutton.png" onClick="pixelbuttonclick()" />
</body>

/* jQuery */

function pixelbuttonclick() {
var pixelbutton = document.getElementById("pixelbutton");

if (pixelbutton.style.src=="images/pixelbutton.png") {
    document.getElementById("pixelbutton").src="images/pixelbutton_press.png";
    }


else if (pixelbutton.style.src=="images/pixelbutton_press.png") {
    document.getElementById("pixelbutton").src="images/pixelbutton.png";
    }

}
```

I'm a huge noob, so less complicated answers, if possible, are appreciated.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm still not quite clear of the difference between JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to place your function in head section for consistency if you haven't.

Your "pixelbutton.style.src" was wrong since the src is an attribute and not in css, but manipulating URL is rather difficult. I agree with Amareswar's answer to use background image in css.

Another way I did this is using the jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pixelbutton").click(function(){
            $("#pixelbutton").css({'display':'none'})
            $("#pixelbutton2").css({'display':'block'});
        })
        $("#pixelbutton2").click(function(){
            $("#pixelbutton2").css({'display':'none'})
            $("#pixelbutton").css({'display':'block'});
        })
    })
</script>
```

and modifying your body code:

```
<img id="pixelbutton" src="images/pixelbutton.png" />
<img id="pixelbutton2" src="images/pixelbutton_press.png" style="display: none;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repalcing URL can use a div with background-image css property and set another class on click of the div  with another image as background image